# I don't know how to add a random cat picture to a Discord Embed

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm new to stack overflow and programming as a whole, so please help, would be very appreciated :D.
so i have a discord bot and i wanna make a command that gives you a random cat picture.
here's the code i have for the command:

```
@client.command()
async def catpics(ctx):
  response = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
  data = response.json()
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Your Requested Cat Pic! <:cat:840334556133589042>", description="Here's your cat pic.", color=discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_image(url=data['url'])
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

when i run the code, it gives me this error:
"File "main.py", line 112, in catpics
embed.set_image(url=data['url'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
, what does this mean? how do i fix this?

Comment: What is data? Is data a set or a dictionary?

Comment: Just replace `embed.set_image(url=data['url'])` with `embed.set_image(url=data[0]['url'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `response.json()` returns a list of dictionaries, and you can't index a list with a string.

```py
>>> response = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
>>> response.json()
[{'breeds': [], 'id': 'dn7', 'url': 'https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/dn7.jpg', 'width': 795, 'height': 1200}]
```

Just replace `embed.set_image(url=data['url'])` with `embed.set_image(url=data[0]['url'])`.

Comment: thanks! i replaced it and the command works now! :D